# How to format the asciidoc for asciidoctor to genrate a downloadable link ? Download is disallowed the flag 'allow-download' is not set

Tags: html, asciidoc, asciidoctor

When an asciidoc document is including a link for download, like this:

```
https://path/to/document/to/be/downloaded/thefilename.xlsm[downloadMe]
```

When the document converted to html using asiidoctor is served,
on a click, chrome based browser (Edge & chrome) do not react and instead print this is the dev console:

Browser dev tools says:

> Download is disallowed, the frame initiating or instantiating the
> download is sandboxed, but the flag 'allow-download' is not set. See
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280

How to format the asciidoc for asciidoctor to genrate a downloadable link ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to format the link using a specific `windows=_blank` "macro attribute":

> `https:/path/to/a/document/to/be/downloaded/filename.ext[downloadMe,window=_blank]`

Information about macro attributes may be found [here](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/macros/link-macro-attribute-parsing/)